# Dirty air filter seal

Tags: engine, maintenance, air-intake, air-filter

Whenever I have had work done in the past that I can't perform myself, timing belt etc every garage I have been too has made a real mess with my air filter.

When I check the filter there is always dirt/oil all over the seal, finger prints etc.

I highly doubt it makes much difference to the engine but just checking with the experts.

Should I change it or just put it back in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the prints are just on the seal, I wouldn't worry about it. You could possibly take some gentle cleaner (Windex or Formula 409 or the like which will clean grease) and make it pretty again. It won't, however, decrease the function of the filter in any way. If they got a bunch of oil on the element itself, you might want to think about it. Really nothing to worry about with your description, though.